# Upgrading one partition to El Capitan while leaving the other on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, partition, upgrade

We have an iMac that is barely still compatible with El Capitan. Right now it runs Mountain Lion okay, and actually it has a smaller partition on the hard drive for another clean installation of Mountain Lion that we don't really use.

I have an El Capitan boot USB drive and an El Capitan install app, and I was thinking about using one of those to upgrade the clean install partition to El Capitan to see how it performs, but I'm hesitant and want to make sure things wouldn't be messed up.

So first of all, does this sound like a good idea? Second, would it be better to boot into the USB drive and choose to install to the clean install partition or should I put the install app on the clean install's Application's folder and run it from there?

Also would doing this risk causing the Mountain Lion restore partition to be deleted? Are there risks of things being messed up, not being able to make Mountain Lion the default boot partition, or other weird things El Capitan would do to the main partition?

[image: terminal output]

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output from the commands `diskutil  list` and `diskutil  cs  list`. I need to know if you are using core storage before trying to answer your question. These commands will not change your computer.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I'll have to get back to you on that.

Comment: Mainly, I just wanted to know if you are using core storage. I was going to post an answer if you were not. I have both Yosemite, El Capitan and Windows 10 installed on my iMac.

Comment: @DavidAnderson OK, see edit with a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can go ahead and  install El Capitan to the smaller partition.

You just need to run the "Install OS X El Capitan" application and select the proper destination volume. I would first use the Disk Utility application to erase this destination volume. You do ***not*** have to use a USB drive to install El Capitan.

During the installation, the Recovery volume following destination volume will be update with the proper code. The Recover volume for Mountain Lion will be unchanged. The result will be two different Recover volumes on your internal disk. Each will be given a different label so you can tell them apart.

During the installation, I was ***not*** asked, if I wanted to use Core Storage. In the event, you are asked, the answer should be `No`.

> I verified this procedure by running the "Install OS X El Capitan" application from an internal Yosemite volume. I installed El Capitan to an external drive. The Yosemite volume was unchanged by the procedure.

I also have had Yosemite and El Capitan installed in different volumes on my internal drive for some time now. You can switch operating systems by selecting the Startup Disk in System Preferences.

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, you recommend using Disk Utility to wipe the "clean install" partition as a new partition, running "Install OS X El Capitan" from within the main Mountain Lion OS, and then I will be able to choose the erased partition as the destination to install it? Also, why *not* use a USB disk or install it from within the test partition?

Comment: My answer is Yes to this: To clarify, you recommend using Disk Utility to wipe the "clean install" partition as a new partition, running "Install OS X El Capitan" from within the main Mountain Lion OS, and then I will be able to choose the erased partition as the destination to install it?

Comment: I installed to a USB 2 external drive. USB 2 is rather slow. If you have USB 3, then things would run much faster. I am not sure what you mean by "or install it from within the test partition"

Comment: Oh, what I meant was, I have a USB bootable image of El Capitan. I could plug it in to a Mac that's not working and boot from the disk to re-install. And what I meant about installing it from within the test partition was that, why not boot in to the "Clean install" partition running 10.8, put the El Capitan installer in the application folder, and open it while running that partition.

Comment: You can use USB bootable installer of El Capitan to install on another Mac. The instructions are given at the site: [Create a bootable installer for OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). You can instruct the El Capitan installer application to install to the current boot volume, but I prefer to do a clean install when possible. (Clean install means erase the destination volume before installing.)

Comment: David, so I've been dragging my feet on this, but with software compatibility issues coming up I think it's time for me to do the upgrade. (Still have installer app, no longer have bootable USB drive.) Before I do it, I was going through everything you'd said, and I do want to get your opinion on this: Would there be any real downside to running the upgrade app from within the secondary partition itself? Intuitively it seems like many fewer steps for me to take and thus less chance that I'd do something wrong, which is why I'm interested in going that route if it would also be okay.

Comment: You can copy the upgrade app to the secondary partition's application folder and run the upgrade while booted from the secondary partition.

Comment: So I did the upgrade and it went fine! And it actually runs pretty well. Thanks again for your help. (The only issue seemed to be that Bluetooth was not functioning, but removing a Bluetooth related file from the library and re-booting twice fixed it.)

Comment: This is the first time someone waited almost 3 years before using one of my answers. I am glad the installation worked out.

Comment: Haha, there's a first time for everything!